# Python csv file

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

Answered: I needed to use append instead of extend. Code below is still not functional due to the fetchAirports function not actually running the getAirport method in another class, so I wouldn't advise attempting to use any of this.

TL,DR; I'm taking user input into a list and writing to a CSV file. The writer is writing each character as an element, not each string.

I'm working on an assignment for my HDip and decided to jazz it up a bit. We're required to read a list of airports from a CSV file, get the data for those airports from another csv, work out the most cost efficient route, and write the best route to a new CSV.

I decided to jazz it up a bit and allow the user to input their own airport codes, writing this to a CSV, or use the existing CSV file. Instead of printing out each code as one entry, it's entering each letter. So I receive a file that reads:

```
P,I,K,
E,D,I,
D,U,B,
A,A,L,
K,O,I,
```

I haven't been able to figure out why this is occurring. Relevant code below.
Main:

```
def main():
atlas = AirportAtlas()
itinerary = Itinerary('747',atlas)
userpref=input("Do you want to enter new itinerary or use existing?\n Please enter 'NEW' or 'OLD'\n")

if "NEW" in userpref.upper():
    itinerary.iRoute=[(input("Enter first IATA code\n")), (input("Enter second IATA code\n")),
                           (input("Enter third IATA code\n")), (input("Enter fourth IATA code\n")), (input("Enter fifth IATA code\n"))]
    itinerary.createList("input.csv")

itinerary.getItin("input.csv")
itinerary.fetchAirports()
```

Itinerary class:

```
import os, csv

class Itinerary:
    def __init__(self,aircraft='747', atlas=None):
        self.iAtlas=atlas
        self.iPlane=aircraft
        self.iRoute=[] #route as a list of strings
        self.iAirportRoute=[] #route as a list of Airport Objects

    def createList(self,filename):
       with open(os.path.join(filename), "w",newline='') as f:
        writer=csv.writer(f,delimiter=",")
        for airport in self.iRoute:
            csvrow = []
            csvrow.extend(airport)
            writer.writerow(csvrow)

    def fetchAirports(self):
        for port in self.iRoute:
            try :
                #upps=port.upper()
                self.iAirportRoute.append(self.iAtlas.getAirport)
            except KeyError:
                print("The following code", port, "is invalid")

    def getItin(self, filename):
        with open(os.path.join(filename),"rt",encoding="utf8") as f:
            csvfilelines=csv.reader(f)
            for row in csvfilelines:
                try :
                    self.iRoute.extend(row)
                except KeyError:
                    #If code isn't found , the airport won't be added to the dictionary
                    continue
```

Any help you guys could give would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: add `print(csvrow)` right after your `csvrow.extend(airport)`.

Comment: Hmmm...Thanks DSM but can you tell me why it's reading each character as an element in a list rather than as one string?

Comment: `extend` isn't how you add an element to a list..

Comment: What should I be using? I was under the impression that's what extend did

Comment: I swapped back to using append, however now the csv contains no commas!

Comment: @VantasStrider `extend` is for when you want to add the elements of one list to another list. `append` is for when you want to add a single thing to a list. `a = [1]; a.extend([2, 3])` results in `a == [1, 2, 3]`; on the other hand, `a = [1]; a.append([2, 3])` results in `a == [1, [2, 3]]`.

Comment: Second hint: now look at where `csvrow = []` is, and the indentation of your `writerow`.